# How to retrieve appid when deployed to cloudbees?

Tags: configuration, cloudbees

In the Cloudbees wiki, [this page](http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/CloudBeesWebXml) explains how to add configuration parameter for an app deployment, using cloudbees-web.xml.

But, is the content of:

```
<appid>APP_ID</appid>
```

injected as a well ? How can I retrieve this value from my application's code ?

Answer (score 1):

My preference is to avoid coding an application to contain explicit references to the container within which it runs. So I would favour using techniques that do not tie your code to CloudBees (a.k.a. us).

Thus I would use a container specific descriptor file that configures a context parameter, then your application just reads the context parameter and uses that parameter directly.

There are two techniques for doing this:

1. [Application Environments](http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/CloudBeesWebXml#HApplicationEnvironments) personally I love this way... though if you want to deploy the application to your own test environment that you have just spun up yourself, your `cloudbees-web.xml` will likely be missing the required environment definition... so better is to use the newer
2. [Configuration Parameters](http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Configuration+Parameters) so that when you need your own test instance you just define the configuration parameters for that test environment and then deploy the *exact same* artifact to that instance... it also prevents the issue of deploying to the test instance with the production environment turned on.

I am sure one of the RUN@ team may well have some other trick such as a System property that tells you the app id... but keep in mind that when running locally, e.g. using a local jetty/tomcat/bees:run container your code will then blow up!

Comment: I am not aware of any intrinsic property. I have used the hostname in the past, assuming you are not using a custom DNS name.

Comment: hostname only works if you are not running background threads where you will be disconnected from the servlet request/response lifecycle...

Comment: good point - I will see if an environment variable can be set for this - as I can see it would be useful information